# Setting element value within an event callback using jQuery

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

A little stumped by this one so I'm hoping you guys can help.

Looks like I may have found an IE-related jQuery bug. Created a small test (included here) which I can dupe the issue. Works fine in Firefox and Chrome and fails in IE8-9.

Issue is that the DIV "podcastStatus" isn't being updated at the correct moment when the update occurs within an event callback. You can test it locally by using IE tools and Firebug and setting breakpoints where I've commented in the code.

Steps:

1. Set breakpoints in Firebug and IE
2. Dev tools according to my comments in the code
3. Click on either "Next" or "Prev"
4. Text in the DIV should change to either "Next" or "Prev" depending on which button you clicked
5. Text in the DIV should then revert back to "Playing..."

I think it's innerHTML-related but I've tried the innerHTML DIV wrapper trick and no-dice.

**NOTE: I've used both .text() and .html() with no resolution.**

Here's the test case:

```
<body>

<style type="text/css">
    #podcastStatus {
        background-color: ButtonHighlight;
        font-size: 120pt;
        font-weight: bolder;
        color: Black;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
        margin:auto; height:200px; width:100%;
        z-index: 100;
    }
</style>

<div id="podcastStatus">Playing...</div>        

<div id="targetBtns">
<input type="button" name="prev" id="prev" value="Prev"/>
<input type="button" name="next" id="next" value="Next"/>
</div>        

<script>
function onButtonClicked(e) {
    switch (e.target.defaultValue) {
        case "Next":
            // Use IE tools or Firebug...
            //Set breakpoint here. Immediate after this executes, DIV text should be updated to "Prev"....
            $('#podcastStatus').html("Prev").show();
            break;
        case "Prev":
            // Use IE tools or Firebug...            
            //Set breakpoint here. Immediate after this executes, DIV text should be updated to "Next"....            
            $('#podcastStatus').html("Next").show();
            break;
    }

    //Set breakpoint here. DIV should show either "Prev" or "Next" at this point...        
    playPause();
}        

function playPause() {
    $('#podcastStatus').text("Playing...").fadeIn('slow');
}   

$( "#targetBtns" ).click( function(event) { onButtonClicked(event) } );

</script>            

</body>
```

Comment: Whoa, I didn't even notice at first who the questioner is--Hi Rey! Having a nice glass of water this evening? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example code causes a div to have its text change to 'Prev' or 'Next' and to be shown. It then calls a function which causes the text of the same DIV to be set to 'Playing...' and tells it to fade into showing--even though it already is showing.

1. The text changes happen so fast you never see the 'Prev' or 'Next' text
2. it will not fade in if it's already showing.

With those two issues, the code *appears* to do nothing in *all* browsers.

All that said, this is how I would modify your JS for consistency, anyway:

```
var $podcastStatus = $( '#podcastStatus' );

function playPause()
{
    $podcastStatus.text( 'Playing...' ).fadeIn( 'slow' );
}   

$( '#targetBtns' )
    .delegate( 'input[type="button"]', 'click', function onButtonClicked( e )
    {
        var text;
        switch( $( this ).val() )
        {
            case 'Next':
                text = 'Prev';
                break;

            case 'Prev':
                text = 'Next';
                break;
        }

        $podcastStatus.html( text ).show();

        playPause();

        e.preventDefault();
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Issue seems to be related to the IE debugger not repainting the text you're stepping through it. Used a setTimeout and now it works which syncs w/ what @JAAulde mentioned.

Comment: I think I had the same problem a few times when debugging IE with Visual Web Developer 2010 Express. Glad you've resolved it!

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciated your feedback and help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer doesn't support the `target` property. Instead, Microsoft invented `srcElement`.

If you check for the existence of `target` and fallback to `srcElement`, your code should work:

```
switch ((e.target || e.srcElement).defaultValue) {
```

But I'd consider using a bit more jQuery and less JavaScript ;)

Comment: IE recognized target because jQuery normalizes the event model. So the code worked fine. It wasn't related to the target as much as the rendering of the text. That was my bigger issue. Thank you though for taking a look at it. I appreciate the help.